# C++ init a class member inside a subclass constructor init list

Tags: c++, constructor

Is there a way to init the member of a class inside the initialisation list of one of its subclasses ? let me explain, since it is way easier to visualise like that:

Inside a class I have a bitfield struct

```
class bitFieldInterface{

struct dataBlock{
uint32_t engineDataRPM : s_engineDataRPM .size;
uint32_t engineDataInstantConsumption : s_InstantConsumption.size;
...
uint32_t vehicleGpsLocation : s_vehicleGEneralInfoGpsLocation.size;
uint32_t vehicleGpsSpeed : s_vehicleGeneralInfoGpsSpeed.size;
...
uint32_t vehicleInfoDimensionX : s_vehicleInfoDimensionX .size;
uint32_t vehicleInfoDimensionY : s_vehicleInfoDimensionY .size;
...
} m_dataBlock;

}
```

in total, there are over 40 distinct fields.

I could just init them all in the constructor init list:

```
bitFieldInterface() :
m_dataBlock.engineDataRPM{s_engineDataRPM.defaultValue},
m_dataBlock.engineDataInstantConsumption{s_engineDataInstantConsumption.defaultValue},
...
m_dataBlock.vehicleGpsLocation{s_vehicleGpsLocation.defaultValue},
m_dataBlock.vehicleGpsSpeed{s_vehicleGpsSpeed.defaultValue},
...
m_dataBlock.vehicleInfoDimensionX{s_vehicleInfoDimensionX.defaultValue},
m_dataBlock.vehicleInfoDimensionY{s_vehicleInfoDimensionY.defaultValue},
...
{}
```

but since there are different categories I wanted to add more structure to my code and divide them into subclasses like so:

```
class EngineData
class vehicleGps
class vehicleInfo
...
```

and inside each class constructor initialize the corresponding fields of the main `class EngineData()`:

```
m_dataBlock.engineDataRPM{s_engineDataRPM.defaultValue},
m_dataBlock.engineDataInstantConsumption{s_engineDataInstantConsumption.defaultValue},
...
{}
```

vehicleGps():

```
m_dataBlock.vehicleGpsLocation{s_vehicleGpsLocation.defaultValue},
m_dataBlock.vehicleGpsSpeed{s_vehicleGpsSpeed.defaultValue},
...
{}
```

and in the main class I would just call each constructor: `bitFieldInterface()`:

```
EngineData{},
vehicleGps{},
vehicleInfo{},
...
{}
```

is there a way to do this, while keeping the `m_dataBlock` inside the `bitFieldInterface` class ?

Comment: Yes? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Please also refer to [How to format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: please click the `?` in the edit box to learn how to format in markdown. It's very common and is used everywhere